# Why does the NVD3.js line plus bar chart example render two charts instead of one?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I put together the following test code based on the example code provided by the NVD3 team at the library's official website. For some reason, I always see two charts drawn on the page: one has the proper labels on the two Y-axes and the proper labels on the X-axis while the second is more compressed vertically, does not have any labels on the Y-axes and has what appears to be data array indices on the X-axis.

The code below assumes the latest versions of both D3 and NVD3 although this behavior still manifests even when using the older version of D3 that the website links to.

Thanks in advance for any help and insight into this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Line + Bar Chart | NVD3.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nv.d3.css"/>
    <style>
        #chart svg {
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart">
        <svg></svg>
    </div>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <script src="nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script>
        var data = [
            {
                'key': 'foo',
                'bar': true,
                'color': 'skyblue',
                'values': [
                    [1431993600000, 31.6882],
                    [1432080000000, 76.1706],
                    [1432166400000, 76.2297],
                    [1432252800000, 75.1944],
                    [1432339200000, 75.1536],
                    [1432425600000, 74.528],
                    [1432512000000, 75.7265],
                    [1432598400000, 75.8659],
                    [1432684800000, 74.6283],
                    [1432771200000, 73.3533]
                ]
            },
            {
                'key': 'bar',
                'color': 'steelblue',
                'values': [
                    [1431993600000, 0.0002997961386257345],
                    [1432080000000, 0.0004418193656404055],
                    [1432166400000, 0.0003122142681920564],
                    [1432252800000, 0.00031651293181407124],
                    [1432339200000, 0.0003845457835685849],
                    [1432425600000, 0.00031934306569343066],
                    [1432512000000, 0.0005163317993040745],
                    [1432598400000, 0.00042575122683577205],
                    [1432684800000, 0.00025057518394496457],
                    [1432771200000, 0.00041715914621428076]
                ]
            }
        ];
        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
                    .margin({
                        top: 30,
                        right: 60,
                        bottom: 50,
                        left: 70
                    })
                    .x(function (d, i) {
                        return i;
                    })
                    .y(function (d, i) {
                        return d[1];
                    });

            chart.xAxis
                    .showMaxMin(true)
                    .tickFormat(function (d) {
                        var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
                        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx));
                    });

            chart.y1Axis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

            chart.y2Axis
                    .tickFormat(function (d) {
                        return d3.format('g')(d)
                    });

            chart.bars.forceY([0, 200]);
            chart.lines.forceY([0]);

            d3.select('#chart svg')
                    .datum(data)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This second char is a focus chart — it allows user to select and magnify particular part of the main chart.
To disable it, just set `focusEnable` option to `false`, like this:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
        .margin({
            top: 30,
            right: 60,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 70
        })
        .x(function (d, i) { return i; })
        .y(function (d, i) { return d[1]; });
        .options({focusEnable: false}); // here it is
    // ...
    return chart;
});
```

P.S. Here's live example of you chart that I've used to figure out an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/7ms6041o/2/ with `focusEnable` option set to `false`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! You are now officially my favorite person of the day. :D

Comment: Your answer is helpful for me too.